# usage of вы гляньте

Tags: словоупотребление

I came across this:

> разве это единственный "паразит"? **Вы гляньте**, как теперь все
>   повадились "дакать". Каждое второе слово - "да".

I realize that гляньте is an imperative, but I don't understand the use of the pronoun вы with it, and additionally it seems like some sort of lead-in to what she says next. Is this correct? Is this comparable to any English usage? My guess from the context is something like **"Have you noticed..."**

Comment: "Look, how..." - what is so problematic in this for you?

Comment: The fact that is "ВЫ гланьте, как..." and not just "Гланьте, как..." and the fact that she uses this verb instead of посмотреть for example. I wondered if there was a special nuance at play that I wasn't picking up on.

Comment: One can say simply "гляньте, как" and "посмотрите, как" and "вы посмотрите, как..." as well

Comment: Using вы adds a tone of argumentative insistence here. I've discussed the usage of pronouns with the imperative here: http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8854/use-of-the-imperative-form-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8/8883#8883

Comment: Thank you, Nikolay, as always for a wonderful, insightful answer. Annix was perplexed that I should find anything "problematic" in the use of a pronoun with an imperative - I'm glad I wasn't the only one curious about this.

Comment: So if I understood everything correctly, this is like saying "Just look at how..." when citing an example of something? (as in my example above)

Comment: Yes, "Just look at how..." is a good rendition.

Comment: IMO this question could benefit from a better (more general) title, such as "Inclusion of explicit subject in imperatives"

Comment: subject or pronoun?

Answer (score 2):

Speaking about the usage of the pronoun together with the imperative, yes, usually it's omitted, but there are some exceptions. And the most common reason to keep the pronoun is a high expressivity, and (sometimes quite aggressive) attempt to persuade.

You may also want to consult this (quite lengthy) article on [Russian Imperative](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2#321). The relevant chapter is 3.2.1.

Answer (score 2):

*Вы* makes this imperative rhetoric.

It's not an actual call to go and look at something, it's a figure of speech.

This is somewhat similar to English "oh" added to the beginning of the sentence.

> Погляди, как он играет // Look at him playing.
>
> Ты погляди, как он играет! // Oh look at him playing!
>
> Ты, погляди, как он играет // You, look at him playing.

Comment: I am not sure why you tacked "go" onto "look". "Погляди" does not really suggest going anywhere.  You could use "just" for emphasis ("just look at him playing") instead of "Oh" in the second case, too. Mentioning it because I've never heard it used that way.

Comment: @VictorBazarov: English "go" doesn't suggest going anywhere either in this case. It means, as Webster puts it, "to engage in something" in this context, similar to Russian *давай-ка*. I used it here to emphasize call to actual action, as opposed to rhetoric figure in the second example.

Comment: @Quassnoi: [go + imperative] always involves going somewhere to do something.

Comment: @CocoPop: taking your word as a native speaker for it. Out of curiosity: does "go" in "go figure" also imply going somewhere? Thanks!

Comment: It's crazy that you asked me that because I thought about it yesterday driving to Miami and "go figure" was the only exception I could come up with :) hahaha   The only other marginal exception is actually quite common: we say "don't go -ing" when we want to categorically warn somebody not to do something we wouldn't put past them: Don't go telling your friends that I'm out of work" (here the speaker know that this person tells her friends everything). "Don't go selling your car when you run out of money. Just ask me and I'll give you more." Elton John had a song: Don't Go Breaking My Heart.

Comment: @cocopop: oh right, I looked it up in Webster's again and it turned out the example for "engage in something" was "go -ing". "Go figure" would be *поди догадайся* in Russian, that could have set me on the wrong track too. But isn't it valid to say someone who's sitting next to a phone "go make this call already!"? I think I have heard something like this in the movies.

Comment: Actually, I think they probably said: Go ahead! Make the call already! "go ahead" is used when someone is hesitating or unsure. However, "go figure" although imperative in form, is only rhetorically so. I means "that doesn't surprise me in the least - I kind of expected it." For example, your friend's son has been in trouble all his life. Then someone tells you he's in jail and you say "go figure!" obviously, with sarcasm. Is this the same force of поди догадайся?

Comment: @CocoPop: the Russian idiom implies genuine surprise.

Answer (score 1):

**Гляньте** - слово из просторечной лексики. Его литературным синонимом является слово **посмотрите**.  *Вы посмотрите, как теперь все повадились "дакать". Каждое второе слово - "да"*.

**Гляньте** is the word of the vernacular style. Its literary synonym is the word **посмотрите**.

Answer (score 1):

"Вы гляньте, ..." это риторическое выражение, и на это указал *Quassnoi*.
Но не каждая конструкция "местоимение + императив" — риторическая.

```
(1) Вы послушайте, вы подумайте, вы вообразите, вы гляньте, ...

(2) Вы сходите, вы ударьте, вы сьешьте, вы напишите, ...

(3) послушайте, подумайте, вообразите, гляньте, сходите, ударьте, сьешьте, ...
```

(1) -- риторическая, "вы" воспринимается скорее во множественном числе;
(2) -- персонифицированный императив, "вы" воспринимается скорее в единственном числе;
(3) -- императив ко второму лицу (лицам) диалога.

Императив везде сохраняется, но **различие заключено в степени направленности,** *узкая-широкая,*  **императива.**

Под *риторической конструкцией* я понимаю широкое обращение, одновременно ко всем и ни к кому в частности. Если это вопрос, то ответ на него не ожидается, потому что ни к кому конкретно в данный момент не обращались. Риторический вопрос действителен перед полной пустотой, обычно, в надежде, что кто-то услышит.
*Императив*, в отличие от риторики, подразумевает лицо, к которому обращаются, и чью реакцию желают вызвать.

```
Сценка.

Человек. Один в комнате. Читает газету. Удивляется. Произносит вслух:

-- Гляньте, как теперь все повадились "дакать". Каждое второе слово - "да".
```

Эта сценка оставляет впечатление чего-то странного, с кем человек там разговаривает? К кому направлен его императив "гляньте"? Для русскоязычного, он говорит сам с собой, возможно, человек не совсем психически здоров.

```
Та же сценка.

-- Вы гляньте, как теперь все повадились "дакать". Каждое второе слово - "да".
```

Здесь русскоязычному ясно, что это риторическое восклицание человека. Всю эту окраску дает местоимение `"вы"` перед "гляньте", сценка в пустой комнате воспринимается нормально, так, как если человек не ждет ничьей реакции на своё восклицание.

Еще более сильные риторические восклицания:

```
Нет, вы гляньте, ...
Нет, вы только погляньте, ...
Нет, вы только послушайте, что он говорит!
Нет, ну вы подумайте, что он говорит!
```